# increment variable value in spark view engine

Tags: loops, spark-view-engine

I try to go through a for each loop and increment value of variable to name my label with below code

```
<set i="0"/>
<div each="var x in Model">

<input name='field-${i}' value='${x.Id}'/>

<set i=i+1 />
</div>
```

but it did not increment the value of 'i' , how can I increment the value of i in above loop

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the built in indexer that Spark creates in a for loop. The above could be written like this:

```
<div each="var item in Model">
   <input name='field-${itemIndex}' value='${item.Id}'/>
</div>
```

Even shorter than the original, and no need to track variables yourself. Also, no need to specifically use `item`, in your case it would be `xIndex` because `x` was your instance.

Comment: You did say this in your answer but I missed it (so thought I'd highlight): The index variable is named yourForEachVariableNameIndex. So it's only called itemIndex, if you named your loop variable index.

Answer (score 1):

With slight modification:

```
<var i="0"/>
<div each="var x in Model">
    <input name='field-${i}' value='${x.Id}'/>
    <set i="i+1" />
</div>
```

this should work.

The initial 'set' has been changed to 'var' and quotes were added around i+1.